# Using Angular DateTime pipe programmatically for hh:mm:ss formats

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, pipe

I'm trying use [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) for HH:MM:SS (or any other documented formats) just as I've used [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) for monetary values.

However, passing my logic a format such as `hh:mm:ss` my values immediately turn to `07:00:00`.

```
time = 'hh:mm:ss';
val = '1:02'; // user entered value
invalids = new RegExp('[^0-9:]{0,6}', 'g'); // time chars only
replaced = String(val).replace(invalids, ''); // remove non-hhmmss characters
let value = this.datePipe.transform(replaced, time); // format the value
console.log(value); // '07:00:00' why!?
```

Here is the repro in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-pipe-hhmmss?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffloating-label%2Ffloating-label.component.ts):67

How can I get the component to accept those predefined formats to force the input value?

Comment: Isn't the *first* argument to `.transform` supposed to the time? Please give a proper [mre].

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe thanks for the feedback however in my use case the user enters a value (see regex forcing time based characters) then I was hoping to use `datePipe` to format it into any format, `HH:MM:SS` in this case.

Comment: Oh so `replaced` is the time and `this.time` is the *format*? Again, [mre].

Comment: I went big on the SB but also rewrote the code here per your instruction. Thanks for explaining kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Angular DatePipe's input is typed as any, but actually requires a Date, or miliseconds, or ISO formatted string which you are not giving it.

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#input-value

> value any  The date expression: a Date object, a number (milliseconds
> since UTC epoch), or an ISO string
> (https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

The data you are passing in does not meet that criteria so it's probably not going to work for you use case unless you can modify it before sending to `datePipe`.